# I need help on 'Cannot find namespace Kind' issue

Tags: node.js, nestjs, apollo

I just updated NestJs to latest (8.3.1) from 7.5, solved the issues that popped out, but I cannot get rid of one of them.

The full error:

```
node_modules/@apollo/federation/dist/composition/utils.d.ts:43:316 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Kind'.
```

Although Kind is a constant imported from the GraphQl module, it seems it does not recognize it. Or maybe is a typescript issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just ran into this too today. Might be something that needs a GitHub issue created.

Comment: Could anyone solve this issue? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were other libraries that were outdated, after I updated all of them, the error disappeared.

Comment: What libraries were causing this issue? I'm having the same issue all of a sudden and cannot figure out what is causing this. Also downgrading @apollo/gateway does not seem to solve it. Thanks for a hint!

Comment: I just ran "npm outdated" on my project and updated all the libs that were mentioned there. Afterwards the error was gone.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `@apollo/gateway@0.48.1` has typing issues. `@apollo/gateway@0.47.0` is broken for GraphQL 15, so you have to downgrade to `@apollo/gateway@~0.46.0`:

```
$ yarn add @apollo/gateway@~0.46.0
```